# Typescript - Is there a way to make composition with functions with the same arguments?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my code :

```
type fnType = ((a: number, b: number) => void) | ((a: number, b: number) => Promise<void>);
```

Is there a way to avoid heavy repetition with function arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is

```js
type Fn<R> = (a: number, b: number) => R;

// your type
type fnType = Fn<void> | Fn<Promise<void>>
```